# Trying to print array elements with certain digits length, but the main() seems like it isn't executed

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, printf

I am using this code. It should create a 30 elements array with random values. Then digitcont function should count the digits and then print the number if the digits are two.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 30

int digitcont(int *num){
    int division;
    int count = 0;
    do {
        division = *num / 10;   // divide by 10
        ++count;                // increase digits count
    } while (division != 0);    // continue until the result is 0.
    if (count == 2){            // if number has 2 digits, it prints the number, else it doesn't print it.
        printf("%d", *num);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int myarray[SIZE] = {0};
    int randstuff = 0;
    printf("test");                 // it doesn't even prints this
    for (int i=1; i<=SIZE; ++i){
        randstuff = rand() % i;     // takes a random number
        myarray[i-1] = randstuff;   // and puts in the array
        digitcont(&myarray[i-1]);
    }
}
```

But something weird is happening, because the main doesn't even reach the print "test", because there's no output.... Why?

**Edit**:

**Ok, I fixed printf problem** by adding `\n` in printf.

But still, the digitcont function seems not working. CPU raises 100% usage...

Comment: `printf("test");` -> `printf("test\n");`, `printf` buffers the content.

Comment: @kiranBiradar wow, that fixed the printf issue. But, why?

Comment: The printf issue is because the `stdout` stream is normally set to line-buffered mode if the C startup code thinks it is connected to a terminal. In line-buffered mode, a newline flushes the stream (i.e. writes anything remaining in the stream buffer). You can also flush the stream explicitly by calling `fflush(stdout);`.

Comment: put a `\n` at the end of that `printf("test");` and you'll see it printed on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function has a bug.

```
    division = *num / 10;   // divide by 10
```

the value of *num is the same within iterations of the loop.

You have to write

```
int digitcont(int *num){
    int division = *num;
    int count = 0;
    do {
        division = division / 10;   // divide by 10
        ++count;                // increase digits count
    } while (division != 0);    // continue until the result is 0.
    if (count == 2){            // if number has 2 digits, it prints the number, else it doesn't print it.
        printf("%d", *num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also it is unclear why the function parameter has a pointer type instead of an integer type.

And the function should do only one thing: to count the number of digits in a number. It is the caller of the function will decide to output a message or not depending on the return value of the function.

The return value of the function equal to 0 does not make sense.

And change this call

```
 printf("test");
```

to

```
puts("test");
```

And after the loop output new line character

```
putchar( '\n' );
```

Comment: >it is unclear why the function parameter has a pointer type instead of an integer type. Why you say so?

Comment: @Mnkisd Because there is no sense to pass a pointer to the function instead fo the original integer value. Usually pointers to objects are passed when the pointed original objects must be changed. But your function does not change the original object.

Comment: thanks for answer. I'm new to C. Shouldn't passing arguments by reference waste less memory?

Comment: @Mnkisd This just confuses readers of the code. The function should be declared at least like  unsigned int digitcont(int  num ); and return the number of digits in the passed argument.

Answer (score 0):

There's no output because `printf()` buffers it's output based on the redirections you have.  If you are printing to the console, `printf()` uses a *buffer until buffer fill or a newline, what comes first*.  And that is the reason you don't see any `test` message in your terminal, because it lacks the `\n` character.  Had you redirected your output to a file (and could you see in real time what is happening on the file, then you should have not seen the `test\n` message, as the behaviour then is *buffer until the buffer is full*.

This is how `printf()` works... just a line `fflush(stdout);` after that printf (even without the `\n`) and you would see the output in your terminal (well, if forgot to add this in the behaviours above: *...or the programmer flushes the buffers out*)